# Makefile adding spaces to variables

Tags: makefile, latex, pdflatex

I am trying to use a makefile in order to compile my story in LaTex. I am trying to use a variable in order to complete the file name for my story. If I simply run make, it works. However, I need to be able to run a specific command from make.

```
pdflatex "\\def\\isdraft{1} \\input{FMPGC.tex}"
```

How would I create a variable from PROJ + OBJS so that I could do something like what I am trying to do below. If I run the below code for make draft, it fails out and APPEARS that it is adding numerous spaces between FMPGC and tex.

How could I combine two variables with a "." symbol between the pair so I can compile my story in the below command. I have also experimented with not escaping the \ symbols and that seems to have no effect.

```
# This makefile compiles my story using LaTex
# Author:
#

# VARS - Variables to be changed for reuse of my script
PROJ = "FMPGC"          # The name of the project
OBJS = "tex"            # The extension for the content
AUXS = "aux"            # The aux extensions
CHAP = "chapters/"      # The chapters
FOO = $(PROJ) += "."
F002 = $(FOO) += $(OBJS)

# Configuration:
CC = pdflatex   # The compiler

# Rules
all:
    $(CC) $(PROJ).$(OBJS)
draft:
    $(CC) "\\def\\isdraft{1} \\input{$(FOO2)}"
```

The current error comes from it not inputting anything into the variable as of right now -

```
pdflatex     "\\def\\isdraft{1} \\input{}"
```

Below seems to be the exact issue.

```
<*> \def\isdraft{1} F
                     MPGC.tex
```

---------------- Updated Make File

```
# This makefile compiles my story using LaTex
# Author:
#

# VARS - Variables to be changed for reuse of my script

# The name of the project
PROJ:=FMPGC
# The extension for the content
OBJS:=tex
# The aux extensions
AUXS:=aux
# The chapters
CHAP:=chapters/

# Configuration:
# The compiler
CC=pdflatex

# Rules
all:
    $(CC) $(PROJ).$(OBJS);
draft:
    $(CC) "\def\isdraft{1} $(PROJ).$(OBJS)";
```

Updated Error ----

```
pdflatex "\def\isdraft{1} FMPGC.tex";
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 21 languages loaded.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

<*> \def\isdraft{1} F
                     MPGC.tex
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

<*> \def\isdraft{1} F
                     MPGC.tex
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

Comment: What is going on with the `FOO = $(PROJ) += "."` and `F002 = $(FOO) += $(OBJS)` lines? What are you trying to do there exactly? Also why is that second line `F002` and not `FOO2`? (You seem to be using `$(FOO2)` in the `draft` target.)

Comment: I removed that section. I was trying to combine the two variables so it becomes a file name with the . between. Please see my errors and the changes I made in the edit.

Comment: The command line looks fine only the error seems to have the odd spacing (and that might be a pdflatex thing). Are `\def\isdraft{1}` and the filename supposed to be a single argument to `pdflatex` like that?

Comment: I fixed it. Going to add an answer when I can. Thanks a ton! It was a combination of me declaring my variables wrong and not having a piece of syntax in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Etan Reisner I was able to fix it after reviewing the documentation.

My make file now looks like this -

```
# This makefile compiles my story using LaTex
# Author:
#

# VARS - Variables to be changed for reuse of my script

# The name of the project
PROJ:=FMPGC
# The extension for the content
OBJS:=tex
# The aux extensions
AUXS:=aux
# The chapters
CHAP:=chapters/

# Configuration:
# The compiler
CC=pdflatex

# Rules
all:
    $(CC) $(PROJ).$(OBJS);
draft:
    $(CC) "\def\isdraft{1} \input{$(PROJ).$(OBJS)}";
```

I can now compile my document and it adds my variable for use inside of LaTex.

Answer (score 5):

In the [The Two Flavors of Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors) section of the GNU make Manual we find:

> If you put whitespace at the end of a variable value, it is a good idea to put a comment like that at the end of the line to make your intent clear. Conversely, if you do not want any whitespace characters at the end of your variable value, you must remember not to put a random comment on the end of the line after some whitespace, such as this:
>
> ```
> dir := /foo/bar    # directory to put the frobs in
> ```
>
> Here the value of the variable dir is ‘/foo/bar    ’ (with four trailing spaces), which was probably not the intention. (Imagine something like ‘$(dir)/file’ with this definition!)

Comment: I removed all spaces but it is still not working. Now it appears there is a space between the F and the MPGC for var PROJ but that is obviously not the case.

Comment: Update the post with the edited makefile (append it don't delete the current contents) and the new erroneous output from running `make`.

Comment: Please see the amended post above.